# MSTest: How to assert positive if one of 3 asserts are valid?

Tags: c#, linq, mstest

I have an IntegrationTest where I want to test the result of a linq query.
The linq query goes something like this

```
where myObject.fieldA.StartsWith(aString) 
   || myObject.fieldB.StartsWith(aString) 
   || myObject.fieldC.StartsWith(aString)
```

Now I want write the test like so:

```
foreach(var result in results)
{
   StringAssert.StartsWith(result.fieldA, aString);
   StringAssert.StartsWith(result.fieldB, aString);
   StringAssert.StartsWith(result.fieldC, aString);   
}
```

but of course that is not correct, because it should assert valid when one of the 3 above is valid.

Any idea how to do that using MSTest ?

Comment: If you do not know which one is true, it seems that your behavior is based on luck (luck driven development). If you have certain input (oracle), you should know which one is true and which ones are false. If that behavior changes, your code is probably broken. Adding the or is like adding if statements to your unit test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work around it by using

```
Assert.IsTrue(
    result.fieldA.StartsWith(astring) || 
    result.fieldB.StartsWith(astring) ||
    result.fieldC.StartsWith(astring)
);
```

Comment: Correct, thanks... I was already close to that, but didn't figure out that of course I had to string.StartsWith :-D.